# Print NASM program on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit excluding DOSBOX, excluding C, and "possibly" Excluding Windows API calls

Tags: api, assembly, 64-bit, nasm

I've been filling myself up with notes trying to successfully create my first program on Windows 7 with NASM, but with a few self imposed stipulations (until I'm ready to move forward). In creating this first program, however, I have a ton of questions.

.

**The stipulations for now are that:**

- I'm running Window 7 SP1 - 64-bit
- I **do not** wish to use DOSBox so Interrupts 0x21-24 are likely not applicable
- I **do not** wish to rely on C so this is all NASM
- I would really like to **avoid** downloading Visual Studio or associated WDK tools if I can (this depends on whether or not I NEED to interact with the Windows API *and relates to Question 2 below*)
- I've downloaded and installed MinGW
- I'm writing my code in Notepad++ and saving as *.asm
- I am linking using "ld" for now, but from what I've read, most seem to recommend "GoLink" (and Alink hasn't been updated in years?). I'll probably migrate to GoLink after I've assured myself that "ld" may be too limiting
- *I want to know if printing is possible without the use of the Windows API or C because of the code below?*

.

*The only code example that has worked for me in some capacity can be found here.*
[nasm is not executing file in Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733967/nasm-is-not-executing-file-in-windows-8)
.

```
;FILE: main.asm
[section] .text
global _main

_main:
    mov eax, 6
    ret         ; returns eax (exits)


Linked:
c:\Users\James\Desktop>nasm -fwin32 main.asm
c:\Users\James\Desktop>ld -e _main main.obj -o main.exe
c:\Users\James\Desktop>main.exe
c:\Users\James\Desktop>echo %errorlevel%
6
```

.

**My questions (a ton):**

1. The fact that in the code above "ret" by itself gives output, although it just returns whatever is in EAX, is there a way to use it (or another directive outside of the Windows API) to return the contents of a variable (hopefully a string variable)? I tried to use ret with DOS calls, but as noted above, that definitely doesn't work because I'm on a 64-bit system.
2. In case I absolutely must use the Windows API, is the only way to interact with it by using the WDK tools? Is there some other way because that last time I downloaded Visual Studio and associated WDK tools it took up a ton of memory and massively slowed down my computer. Is there another way to make programs give output or print to the screen either by using internal commands or some other method to use API calls? One thread I admittedly skimmed (amidst 40 more tabs I have open) mentions *"Russinovich's Windows Internals"* but not a direct answer. At current every time I use code with the extern commands "ld" tells me that the references to commands like WinMain/WinMain@16 are undefined. In the same vein is there a table I can consult containing accurate calls to the API (i.e. _ExitProcess@4 vs. ExitProcess). I found this link to what  think may be the NT API but I'm not sure it applies given my stipulations, but in reality, I'm just kind of confused:
   http://j00ru.vexillium.org/ntapi/
3. In bits of code I've encountered I've seen directives for *[Bit 16], [Bit 32],* and *[Bit 64]*. *[Bit 16]* is likely ignorable, but I'm confused by the [Bit 32] and [Bit 64] for the following reasons which may not even be related: Via the code above I'm using the command, "nasm **-fwin32** main.asm", then I'm linking it successfully and going on to receive output. For some reason - though I have not read the full "ld" documentation yet - when I use the command "nasm **-fwin64** main.asm" and link it in the same way I receive an error saying "main.obj: File not recognized: File format not recognized". I don't understand why differentiating between 32 and 64 while I'm on a native 64-bit machine causes an error although this probably is just unique to ld.

.

In the meantime I'll be reading this question and will post an update it if helps: [Executable isn't compatible with 64 bits processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171512/executable-isnt-compatible-with-64-bits-processor)

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer some parts in great detail, so I expect somebody either putting up better answer, or feel free to edit this one.

1. you are linking against default clib, so your `_main` is called after Clib is initialized, the `ret` with value in `eax` is like `return 6;` in C++. Then Clib correctly destructs everything and calls windows exit process with exit code 6. You can return only `int` from `_main`, and I'm not even sure if full `int` is propagated to exit process call, or only 8 bit value is used. So you can return single char in ASCII encoding, if you treat that number as char.
2. You must call Windows API, if you want to display something in console/window, or write something into file, ie. do any output (and of course also for input). There's no peripheral available to win32/64 executable directly, like in DOS CGA/EGA/VGA text modes accessible trough `int 10h` or video ram at B800:0000. Any try to access some I/O peripheral directly should result into access violation. Only Win API should be legal for user-level application code.

How much of WDK you need I have no idea, haven't developed anything for windows for years. I think it's even possible to create executable without WDK, which would provide correct externs and dependencies on kernel32.dll and similar, but the amount of effort is way beyond simply using proper parts of WDK or clib from MinGW.

3. I think your linker is set to default to 32b executable, you have to figure out what kind of object format is produced by nasm for `-fwin64` and how link that one with ld.

Why the difference. The 64b OS can run 32b binaries. But you can't mix 32/64 in single executable so easily (if at all). So you are either producing 32b or 64b binary, and you have to adjust everything to it (asm instructions used, directives and options, and WinAPI calls).

Comment: Thank you Ped7g. Your answer gave me quite a few leads regarding how to rectify my problem. Confirmation of what I suspected regarding needing the API and the WDK is unfortunate, but I'll start to redirect my reading toward it. Thanks so much, man. I really appreciate it.